# Logging of warnings and errors are not written to log file in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, logging, svn

I've created a migration script in PowerShell for SVN to Git and I would to log the output of the command `git svn clone`. When I run this like below, then I see that some lines like warnings and errors are not written to the log file. The rest of the lines are written to `logs.txt`.

```
git svn clone "https://subversion/repo" "repo" > logs.txt
```

Same thing with

```
git svn clone "https://subversion/repo" "repo" | Out-File -FilePath logs.txt
```

I've also tried to use `Start-Transcript logs.txt` and `Stop-Transcript` but that logs nothing to the log file.

How could I log the warnigs and the errors to that log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect stderr to the file. Notice the `2`

```
git svn clone "https://subversion/repo" "repo" 2> logs.txt
```

1 is stdout
2 is stderr

To redirect stdout and stderr. Redirect stderr into stdout

```
git svn clone "https://subversion/repo" "repo" > logs.txt 2>&1
```